# Compare semi-large json files in Powershell stuck

Tags: powershell

I have two json files (about 20mb each).
Structure is something like that

```
{
    "Property1":  [
                 "https://testweb.site"
             ],
    "Property2":  "abc",
    "Property3":  [
                "7676"
            ],
    "Property4":  "some string",
    "Property5":  "some string",
    "Property6":  "test",
    "Property7":  "C:\\Folder\\Test\\file.txt"
}
```

What I do:

```
$oldContent = Get-Content file1.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$newContent = Get-Content file2.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$diff = Compare-Object $oldContent $newContent -Property Property1, Property2, Property3 ...
```

I should compare the selected properties and find what is new in json2.

The problem:
This has been working for the last few months, but now is like stuck in forever on the compare step.
Doesn't consume Memory or CPU. I'm not sure if the compare is too complicated or something else.

Questions:
Is there any other better way to make this comparison?
Any suggestion what is the reason?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using? `ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable` in PowerShell 7 might enable you to write a faster comparison algorithm...

Comment: How deeply nested are the JSON files? I. e. do these properties only consist of either scalar values or arrays of scalar values?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Thank you. Not the best performance, but at least is working again.

Comment: @zett42, Scalar values only